# Eliminar datos duplicados de una lista que esta en un Page<t> listpage en java

Tags: java, jpa, java-8

Tengo unos datos duplicados por que contienen el mismo ID en la db necesito de esos dejar solo uno ( Si existen 5 columnas con un mismo ID necesito mostrar solo 1 de esos 5.

Como puedo leer lo siguiente para eliminar datos duplicados

```
Page<Imagenes> lista = service.getAllimagenes(pageable);
model.addAttribute("list", lista);
```

Comment: *”mostrar solo 1 de esos 5”* ¿Cuál?

Comment: Cualquiere puede ser no importa solo necesito que de esos 5 solo quede uno si hay 5 filas con el id 2 pues solo debe quedar una fila con el id no importa cual solo que quede uno de cada id

Comment: que versión de java usas?

Comment: @RuslanLópez la versión de java que uso es Java 8

Comment: ¿Vienen de una base de datos? Lo puedes resolver desde SQL, de lo contrario, habría que implementarle `Comparator` ó `Comparable` a la clase `Imagenes`.

Comment: Si vienen de una base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar el stream API de la siguiente manera:

```
Page<Imagenes> lista = Optional.ofNullabe(service.getAllimagenes(pageable))
  .map( lista-> lista.stream()
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
  .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Esto lo que hace es primero obtiene tu lista y verifica si es nulo, si no es nulo continúa, si no regresa una lista vacía; luego convierte tu lista a un stream, le quita los duplicados con `distinct()` y te lo regresa como una lista.

Comment: En esta me genera error no sirven con ningun import no se cual deberia usar pero los que intente no me dejan

Comment: Lo que puse es Java standard, tal vez deberías de hacer una nueva pregunta al respecto, yo creo tu ide está mal configurado